# Cocos2d-x opengl error in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, cocos2d-x

my windows is saying device driver is up to date. but in my visual studio its giving error opengl higher version required.

i attached the error screenshot. 
     [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [specsheet](http://www.taiwanpcsources.com/intelgraphics.htm) your graphics hardware supports up to OpenGL 1.4 but not 1.5. So you need a different graphics card or computer to launch cocos2d-x apps under windows.

Comment: Also, from my expeirence, Intel graphic card drivers (especially older ones) often lie a bit. They support feature X of version Y, but still fail to report version Y (for whatever reason).

Comment: Yeah I remember that well. We had different code paths specific to certain Intel chipsets and even drivers because they lied, like you said. Worst part is where they were simply emulating the features in software, so as soon as you used feature X it could mean the difference between decent 30 fps and a 0.3 fps slideshow.